# Least obtrusive method of resetting default gpo objects

Tags: group-policy

In my early days of fiddling with our AD domain I modified the default gpo objects. Now I want to reset them back to default and ensure they are not used this time around.

I found the dcgpofix utility but the documentation states that it's meant for disaster recovery scenarios only.

I also found a [kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/556025) that describes how to manually recreate these gpo's then edit the guid in the sysvol folder. I'm good with all of that up until step #7 where it talks about ADSI scripting.

The key thing here is that I don't want to break my domain in the process of doing this. So which way is going to be best for me to accomplish this? Is there another method i've not discovered yet?

We run Windows Server 2008 SP2.

Comment: This is where change control comes in ;-)   I am guessing you didn't backup the GPOs?

Comment: Step 1. Backup all of your GPO's. Step 2. Make a copy of the default GPO's. Step 3. Audit the GPO copies for settings that you need to define in new GPO's or that you need to redefine in the default GPO's. Step 4. Run gpofix.